# Serverside paging in dgrig.io

Tags: dgrid

I have implemented dgrid in imy projects. it is working fine. I want to implemented serverside pagination to returned only current page index record instead of loading all the record in store. I did some search but could not find the solution

Please help !!

Thanks,
Mayur

Comment: Have you tried the `fetchRange` API? Read [Collection Documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Collection.md#fetchrangestart-start-end-end).

Comment: Yes, I am using this but it only fetch record from store but I want to implement he Ajax call when page index changed so it will fetch only pageindex * pagesize record